# Bootsrap 4 input-group-prepend with inline radio labels not inline

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In Bottstrap 3 I could have two radio inut with inline labels before an input text this way

[image: 2 radio inputs with inline labels]

```
             <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <label>
                    <input checked type="radio"value="Mrs">Mrs
                  </label>
                </span>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="Mr" >Mr
                   </label>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
             </div>
```

I am trying to set it the same way with Bootstrap 4

```
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <label class="form-group-label">
                        <input checked type="radio" value="Mrs">Mrs
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr">Mr
                    </label>
                </div>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name">
            </div
```

but the labels are not inine with the radio inputs ..

where am I wrong ?
thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap them in divs with `input-group-text` class.

Also, add the `pb-0` class additionally to `input-group-text` like so: `input-group-text pb-0`

Here's the right way to do it in Bootstrap 4:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text pb-0">
                        <label class="form-group-label">
                            <input checked type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs"> Mrs
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-text pb-0">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr"> Mr
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, add the `pb-0` class additionally to `input-group-text` like so: `input-group-text pb-0`

Comment: Thanks for your answers...  if I compare you code and mine .. it's the same, excepted  the div.container, div.row and div.col that I did not show up... BUT you added the link to cdn bootstrap v4... and Eureka! I checked my Boostrap version.. still v4-beta-3 , in which there was abug related to my issue...   upgrading to Bootstrap v4 final release solve it !!!!

Comment: Yes, but check my previous comment also. The crucial part was the div with the `input-group-text` class. And adding the `pb-0` class to that is also needed.

Answer (score 1):

use form-check and form-check-label class instead of form-group like i use in the below code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="">1 radio button
  </label>
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="">2 radio button
  </label>
</div>
```